# Saving a recorded video in a Safari webapp on iOS device

Tags: html, ios, iphone, video

I'm using the following code to allow a user to capture video while on my web app.

```
<input id="getvideo" type="file" accept="video/*" capture="camera" />
```

The camera opens fine and it's possible to record a video. Is it possible to allow the user to save the video to his/her camera roll, or to do that automatically? I don't want the videos to be lost if they're not uploaded.